# 120Hz refersh rate not listed in settings on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: display, 22.04

I used to have a 120hz display refresh rate on Ubuntu 20.04, but after updating to Ubuntu 22.04, the 120hz option is not listed anymore in display settings.

Laptop Model: ASUS ExpertBook P2451FB
Kernel version: 5.15.0-41-generic
Gnome version: GNOME Shell 42.2

Display refresh rate:

[image: Display refresh rate]

Comment: Does it have a Nvidia graphics and have you installed the correct drivers?

Comment: yes, it does have nvidia graphics and driver installed.

Comment: I upgraded to 22.04 today and I have the same issue , my laptop built-in screen is 120hz screen but max shown in the settings is 60.10 hz!!!